# Ag grid cellrenderparams is not getting called

Tags: angular, ag-grid

I have code like given below, I need to call a method for each `ag grid` row and this method takes the parameter of that rows, but when i run the application `ag grid` is rendered but `this.fnToGetClearingCenterOptions` is not getting called. Any leads will be appreciate

```
if (columnField === 'clearingCenter') {
        complexColumnField.cellRenderer = InversisAgGridFrameworkComponentsEnum.DROPDOWN_CELL_RENDERER;
        complexColumnField.cellRendererParams = { options: this.fnToGetClearingCenterOptions, objectAsValue: true };
}
```

Comment: if (columnField === 'clearingCenter') {
        complexColumnField.cellRenderer = InversisAgGridFrameworkComponentsEnum.DROPDOWN_CELL_RENDERER;
        complexColumnField.cellRendererParams = {
          options: this.fnToGetClearingCenterOptions(this),
          objectAsValue: true
        };
      }
i tried above method, am getting intance of current component, but i need the each row data of agrid

Comment: if (columnField === 'clearingCenter') {
        complexColumnField.cellRenderer = InversisAgGridFrameworkComponentsEnum.DROPDOWN_CELL_RENDERER;
        complexColumnField.cellRendererParams = {
          options: (params: ICellRendererParams) => this.fnToGetClearingCenterOptions(params),
          objectAsValue: true
        };
      }
i tried this method too, after rendering fnToGetClearingCenterOptions is not getting called

Comment: Can you create a stackblitz or plunker that demonstrates your issue?  Altering one of the examples from the ag grid website is usually the best way to start